# Index of javascript object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects in javascript, something like

`var arrayobj = [{a:'a'},{b:'b'},{c:'c'}]` (but with more complex values).

Now I check the index of some object manually, like `arrayobj[1]`

And I got `Object {b: "b"}`

Now I type `arrayobj.indexOf({b:'b'});`
and the response is `-1` (aka not found).

Anyone could tell me why this happens? I have read the documentation on indexOf method and arrays, but I still have no clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't start sentence with "SO"!

Comment: If you want to find the index just use `findIndex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` checks for equality (specifically strict equality, `===`, but it doesn't matter for this question). Two different objects are not equal to each other even if they have the same properties. The object in your array and the one you pass to `indexOf` are *different* objects, and so they don't match.

If you searched for the *same* object, it would find it:

```js
var b = {b:'b'};
var arrayobj = [{a:'a'},b,{c:'c'}];
console.log(arrayobj.indexOf(b)); // 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use ```JSON.stringify``` in this particular case then.

Comment: @alexi2: There is no "pass by reference" in JavaScript **at all**. Please also ensure you don't overwrite overlapping edits.

Comment: @DanielFernandez dont do that. That has an awful performance, also the serialization is not guaranteed to be equal. Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead, with a custom comparer.

Comment: @DanielFernandez: Re Lux's point: https://jsfiddle.net/6px1ss38/ If you're trying to find the object by some criteria, `find` (or `some` if you don't want to polyfill `find` on older browsers) is the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

The [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

`arrayobj` is an array of objects, In first case `arrayobj[1]` it will return the element at index 1.

In second case `arrayobj.indexOf({b:'b'})` is  not referring to the object which in the `arrayobj` but it is a different object.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayobj.indexOf({b:'b'})
```

You are supplying a new object in the indexOf method although contents are same. IndexOf will check for strict equality so references of the objects need to be the same

Answer (score 1):

When you call `arrayobj.indexOf({b:'b'})` the Object `{b:'b'}` is different from the object in your array. These 2 objects have the same "value" but are distinct in the memory.

For exemple if you do this :

```
var object = {b:'b'}
var arrayobj = [{a:'a'},object,{c:'c'}]
```

or

```
var arrayobj = [{a:'a'},{b:'b'},{c:'c'}]
var object = arrayobj[1]
```

`arrayobj.indexOf(object)` will return 1 because it's really the same object and not a "copy"

Answer (score -2):

Javascript IndexOf function will work only for value types and not for reference types in your case. Like when you are passing {b:'b'} to indexOf function then it is all in all a complete different object / reference. If you first fetch object from list and then check that reference in list then it will definitely return greater then -1 if object / reference exist

```js
var arrayobj = [{a:'a'},{b:'b'},{c:'c'}]; 
var obj = arrayobj[1]; 

console.log(arrayobj.indexOf(obj)); console.log(arrayobj.indexOf({b:'b'}));
```

you can use for loop instead of built-in function.

Comment: I have improved my response. please check if it fulfills your requirements